# Why this function is not tail recursive?

Tags: scala, recursion

I have wrtten the following function for pascal triangle. Why the call

```
pascal_cont(a-1, b-1, (x:Int) => pascal_cont(a, b-1, (y:Int) => cont(x + y)))
```

is not tail recursive ?

```
def pascal(c: Int, r: Int): Int = {
  def pascal_cont(a:Int, b:Int, cont: (Int) => Int): Int = {
    if (a==0 || a==b) cont(1)
    else pascal_cont(a-1, b-1, (x:Int) => pascal_cont(a, b-1, (y:Int) => cont(x + y)))        
  }

  pascal_cont(c,r,n => n)  
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Scala compiler cannot optimize any (theoretically) tail-recursive function, as it translates them to a while-loop. It for example also is unable to optimize mutually tail-recursive functions. You can use the [trampoline](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call) pattern to mitigate this.

In Scala, [`scala.util.control.TailCalls`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.util.control.TailCalls%24) contains the necessary utilities. This will turn into:

```
def pascal(c: Int, r: Int): Int = {
  import scala.util.control.TailCalls._

  def pascal_cont(a:Int, b:Int, cont: (Int) => TailRec[Int]): TailRec[Int] = {
    if (a==0 || a==b) cont(1)
    else tailcall {
      pascal_cont(a-1, b-1, (x:Int) =>
        pascal_cont(a, b-1, (y:Int) => cont(x + y)))
    }
  }

  pascal_cont(c,r,n => done(n)).result
}
```

Comment: thanks, Can you please explain why scala compiler can't optimize this tail call. I think F# is able to do so in this case

Comment: @Tinku That, unfortunately, is a limitation of the JVM. Scala compiler can't do much about it.

Answer (score 4):

If you add the `@tailrec` annotation on the `pascal_cont` function you'll get the following error:

```
[error] ....scala:18: could not optimize @tailrec annotated method pascal_cont: it contains a recursive call not in tail position
[error]         pascal_cont(a-1, b-1, (x:Int) => pascal_cont(a, b-1, (y:Int)=> cont (x + y)))
[error]                                                     ^
[error] one error found
```

So the call inside the lambda expression is not in tail position, and that's why it's not tail recursive

Comment: yes I was getting the same error but IMHO (theoretically) pascal_cont is at tail position and scala compiler is not optimizing it.

Comment: The call to `pascal_cont` that the arrow is pointing to is *not* in tail position, because the *other* call to `pascal_cont` on the same line is evaluated after it.